# How to create flutter widget list using list builder?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `items` argument where I have to assign list widget, it's looks like below

```
items: [
    CachedNetworkImage(
        imageUrl: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534531173927-aeb928d54385?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fm=jpg&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&raw_url=true&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870",
        height: double.infinity,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
    CachedNetworkImage(
        imageUrl: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1489824904134-891ab64532f1?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fm=jpg&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&raw_url=true&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1031",
        height: double.infinity,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
    )
],
```

Same thing I'm trying by a dynamic list , where my data looks like

```
List <Carousel> carousels = [
    const Carousel(
        imageUrl: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534531173927-aeb928d54385?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fm=jpg&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&raw_url=true&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870"
    ),
    const Carousel(
        imageUrl: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1489824904134-891ab64532f1?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fm=jpg&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&raw_url=true&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1031"
    ),
    const Carousel(
        imageUrl: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1628964178609-aec11c666040?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fm=jpg&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&raw_url=true&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=871"
    ),
    const Carousel(
        imageUrl: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1505705694340-019e1e335916?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fm=jpg&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&raw_url=true&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1032"
    ),
];
```

Now in items I have used list builder to get list widget in items

```
items: [
            ListView.builder(
                itemCount: carousels.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return CachedNetworkImage(
                    imageUrl: carousels[index].imageUrl,
                    height: double.infinity,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  );
                },
            ),
 ]
```

Here I'm getting error `Another exception was thrown: Null check operator used on a null value`, How can I create widget list in items from carousels list ?

Comment: Where is the error coming from? From which line?

Comment: Use ListView.builder as you would a widget. It should not go into a list as you have it here.

Comment: @DanHarms would you please give an example ?

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/lists/long-lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this example code:

```
List<Widget> _listItem = [];

for(var imageWidget in carousels){
   Widget newWidget = CachedNetworkImage(
                    imageUrl: imageWidget.imageUrl,
                    height: double.infinity,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  );
  _listItem.add(newWidget);
}

items = _listItem;
```

Answer (score 1):

```dart
items =  carousels.map( (Carousel c) => 
  CachedNetworkImage(
    imageUrl: c.imageUrl,
    height: double.infinity,
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
  )
);
```